# What does the verb 'designate' mean?

Tags: verbs, passive-voice

In this following context, how should I understand the verb 'designate'?

Should I understand it as a passive form: “kamma-formations” (sankhårå), is designated as such merely rebirth-producing volition.?

Context:

> The kamma-process (kamma-bhava) in this ninth proposition is,
> correctly speaking, a collective name for rebirth-producing volition
> (cetanå) together with all the mental phenomena associated therewith;
> while the second link, “kamma- formations” (sankhårå), **designates** as
> such merely rebirth-producing volition. But in reality both links
> amount to one and the same thing, namely kamma.

Source: P. 39
''Fundamentals of Buddhism''
by Nyanatiloka Mahåthera

Comment: Hi. Have you looked up the verb in a dictionary?  That's where you should start.

Comment: I'd stop reading that book; or at least find a copy in its original language. Whoever translated that should get a new job.

Comment: The sentence with "designates" isn't grammatical, so I can't say what the purpose of anything is. Removing "as such" would make it grammatical, and the simplified form is, "*The second link designates rebirth-producing volition". Here, "*the second link*" is the subject of "*designates*" and "*rebirth-producing volition*" is its direct object.